# Un login y un control de sesiones más seguro

Tags: php, pdo, login, session, seguridad

Estoy trabajando en un login, para privatizar un poco una aplicación web que estoy haciendo. Mis conocimientos no es que sean básicos, pero tampoco los mejores y necesito ayuda.

No hay método de registro. El registro lo haré yo personalmente desde la base de datos. Lo que necesito es consejos o formas de hacer este login y posteriormente, los controles de sesión, más seguros, más fiables, una mejor estructura de los documentos .php en el directorio raíz...

De momento, lo único que estoy aplicando es PDO y las sentencia `prepare` para evitar inyecciones SQL.

La estructura de los documentos son:

- login.php (Aquí esta el formulario, y donde se ejecutan las funciones). 
  Este es el código PHP que hay antes de la cabecera para gestionar el login:

  ```
  if (isset($_POST['entrar'])) {
      require "functions.php";
      $error = [];
      $user = ValidUser($error);
      if(empty($error)){
          logearUsuario($user);
          header("Location: application.php");
      }
  }
  ```

  Los nombres de las variables a recoger por el form son: user(usuario), pass(password) y entrar(submit)
- conn.php (En este documento está lo necesario para la conexión a la base de datos, en está caso MySQL, pero en un futuro cambiará a PostgreSQL. Se trata de una función que engloba a todo lo necesario para conectarme)

  ```
  function connection(){

      try{

          $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost; dbname=controlusuarios';
          $userBBDD = 'root';
          $passBBDD = '';
          $conn  = new PDO($dsn, $userBBDD, $passBBDD);
          return $conn;

      }catch(Exception $e){

          die('Error: ' . $e->GetMessage());

      }
  }
  ```
- functions.php (Contiene varias funciones. Una para validar al usuario, y otra para logearlo. La condición de logeo se produce en el documento login.php)

  ```
  function validUser(&$error){

      if((!isset($_POST['user'])) || (!isset($_POST['pass']))){
          $error[0] = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos.";
          return null;
      }
      $user = $_POST['user'];
      $pass = $_POST['pass'];
      if(($user == '') || ($pass == '')){
          $error[0] = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos.";
          return null;
      }else{

          $con = connection();
          $sql = "SELECT name FROM usuarios WHERE name = :user AND password = :pass";
          $query = $con->prepare($sql);
          $query-> bindParam(':user', $user);
          $query-> bindParam(':pass', $pass);
          $query-> execute();
          $contador = $query -> rowCount();
          if($contador != 1){
              $error[0] = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos.";
              return null;
          }
          $con = null;
          return $user;
      }

   }

   function logearUsuario($user){

      session_start();
      $_SESSION['name'] = $user;

   }
  ```

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código que llevas hecho para proponerte mejoras? Las respuestas que solicitan conocimientos muy amplios suelen cerrarse rápidamente :( sé algo más específico y estaremos encantados de asesorarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aviso Oscar, ya he aportado el código que implemento.

Comment: Te comento los mismos problemas que le vi a otro usuario preguntando sobre su login hace unos días: 1) el id de sesión no se cambia después de un cambio de estado en el login; 2) no penalizas los fallos; 3) tienes la información de conexión a la base de datos en el propio código.

Comment: para ofrecer una mejor seguridad a una aplicación lo mas recomendables es el uso de framework ademas mejorar el rendimiento de los trabajo y le evita la parte de ofrecer la seguridad a tu aplicaciones, le sugiero laravel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No soy un experto en seguridad, pero basándome en el código que has compartido, veo algunos problemas/puntos que podrían mejorarse:

1. **El id de sesión no se cambia después de un cambio de estado en el login**

   Realmente no se ve mucho cómo tratas la sesión, pero a simple vista parece que la abres cuando el usuario se loguea (no sé si se abre antes o no) y guardas el nombre del usuario, sin parecer que se haga nada más.

   Regenerar el id de sesión cada vez que hay un cambio en el nivel de privilegios de un usuario (p.e. cuando se loguea o cuando se desloguea) es una [práctica recomendada por OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet#Renew_the_Session_ID_After_Any_Privilege_Level_Change) que sirve para evitar múltiples ataques como los de [secuestro de sesión](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secuestro_de_sesi%C3%B3n), [fijación de sesión](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation) o [cabalgamiento de sesión](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) (conocido por sus siglas en inglés CSRF o XSRF).

   En PHP puedes regenerar el id de sesión usando [`session_regenerate_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php), que aplicado a tu código se vería algo así:

   ```
   function logearUsuario($user){

       session_start();
       session_regenerate_id();
       $_SESSION['name'] = $user;

   }
   ```

   ---
2. **La sesión parece no expirar**

   De nuevo, realmente no se ve mucho de cómo tratas la sesión, pero cuando inicias sesión parece que sólo guardas el nombre de usuario, sin nada más.

   Sería ideal que guardaras la fecha de logueo y luego, cada vez que se realice una operación o se cargue una página, comprobar la fecha y verificar que esté dentro de un rango apropiado para realizar una acción apropiada (actualizar o cerrar sesión).

   Por ejemplo, si han pasado más de 10 minutos sin acción, expirar la sesión (regenerando id con lo expuesto en el punto anterior) y mandar al usuario al login. Y si no han pasado más de esos 10 minutos, entonces actualizar el contador de nuevo para darle 10 minutos más.

   Como se indica en la [página de OWASP sobre expiración de sesiones](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet#Session_Expiration) (traducción mía):

   > Para minimizar el tiempo que un atacante puede lanzar un ataque en tu sesión activa y secuestrarlas, es obligatorio poner tiempos de caducidad para cada sesión, estableciendo un tiempo en el que una sesión permanecerá activa.

   Deben tomarse medidas para cerrar la sesión cuando expire tanto en el lado del cliente como del servidor (aunque aquí sólo vemos la parte de PHP).

   ---
3. **No penalizas los fallos**

   Cuando un usuario pone mal su contraseña, simplemente le muestras un mensaje de error y ya está. ¿Qué pasa si el usuario no ha cometido un fallo sino que es un atacante probando a ver si hay suerte y acierta tu contraseña?

   Al no penalizar los fallos al loguear, el código es vulnerable a ataques de [fuerza bruta](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_de_fuerza_bruta). Un atacante (que podría ser un programa/bot) sólo tiene que mandar muchos intentos de contraseñas hasta que alguna funcione y tenga acceso a la cuenta privilegiada.

   Una solución a los [ataques de fuerza bruta en el login](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Periodic_Table_of_Vulnerabilities_-_Brute_Force_Login) sería añadir algún tipo de bloqueo después de varios intentos. Por ejemplo: después de X fallos, bloquear la cuenta por M minutos. Y si después de pasado ese tiempo se vuelve a fallar, aumentar el valor de M siguiendo algún patrón de severidad.

   Otra posible solución sería requerir un CAPTCHA después de X intentos fallidos y cada vez que se vuelva a fallar.

   ---
4. **La información de conexión a la base de datos está en el propio código**

   Como se indica [esta página de OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Use_of_hard-coded_password) y [también en esta otra](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Management:_Hardcoded_Password) (traducción mía):

   > Tener las contraseñas escritas en el código puede comprometer la seguridad del sistema en maneras que pueden no ser fácilmente remediadas.
   >
   > Nunca es una buena idea tener una contraseña escrita directamente en el código. No sólo permite que todos los desarrolladores del proyecto vean la contraseña, sino que también hace resolver el problema bastante difícil. Una vez que el código está en producción, esa contraseña no se puede cambiar sin parchear el software. Si la cuenta protegida por esa contraseña acaba comprometida, los dueños del sistema estarán forzados a elegir entre seguridad o disponibilidad.

   También, si por cualquier motivo el servidor deja de procesar el código PHP correctamente y se muestra como texto plano (algo raro, pero podría ocurrir), los datos de conexión serán visibles para cualquiera.

   Idealmente, la información de conexión a la base de datos se encontrará en un fichero separado y fuera de la raíz del sitio web. De ese modo no será accesible desde fuera del servidor, y no estarán al alcance de posibles fisgones (externos o internos).

   ---
5. **Las claves no están hasheadas**

   Esto es un problema si alguien consigue romper en tu sistema y acceder a la base de datos: los sistemas de login deben estar diseñados teniendo en cuenta la posibilidad de que en algún momento puedan fallar y los datos acaben comprometidos ([como se menciona en OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Design_password_storage_assuming_eventual_compromise)).

   En ese sentido, es esencial proteger la cuenta del usuario y tener las contraseñas en texto plano en la base de datos es una mala idea. No debes guardar la contraseña en sí, sino una *representación* de la contraseña.

   Para ello debes *hashear* la contraseña al guardarla en la base de datos y luego verificar la contraseña pasada en el formulario con el hash para hacer la comprobación (en PHP se podría usar [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)).

   La ventaja de usar hash sobre algoritmos de encriptación, es que encriptando una contraseña puede haber maneras de descriptarla; En cambio con hashing, no hay vuelta atrás. Si la base de datos acabase comprometida, al menos las contraseñas del usuario no se habrían perdido (sé que para ti puede no ser un gran consuelo, pero para el usuario puede serlo teniendo en cuenta que muchos usan las mismas contraseñas de un sitio a otro).

---

Aparte de eso, se podrían hacer algunos comentarios sobre cómo parece que se gestionan las conexiones a la base de datos (conectándose y desconectándose con cada petición), aunque sería más a nivel de rendimiento que de seguridad.

Y también habría que evaluar algunas otras cosas que no se pueden ver en el código compartido. Por ejemplo: ¿usas HTTPS para el logueo? ¿cómo se guardan los datos en la base de datos?

Puedes encontrar más recomendaciones de seguridad en la [página de OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) (y en particular para [sesiones](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet)).

Comment: Muchas gracias por estas soluciones. Espero que con los años, consiga tanta experiencia como la que tú aportas. Un saludo.

Comment: @Pelayo, poco podemos mejorar la respuesta de Álvaro, salvo comentar que implementar medidas contra CSRF en tus formularios (como mínimo en los de login y modificación de datos) es muy importante, por lo que si satisface tu pregunta deberías marcarla como correcta (pulsando el símbolo ✔ situado a la izquierda). Si más adelante otra persona redacta una nueva respuesta mejor que ésta podrás marcar la nueva como correcta.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, me encantó. Detalles: en (1) conviene forzar que elimine la sesión vieja con `session_regenerate_id(true);`, y en (2) dependiendo el caso de uso, en vez de regenerar, iría por `session_unset(); session_destroy();`.